# Looping and appending to a list

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

```
def makelist():
    list = []
    initial = [0, 100]
    a = 1
    while a <= 10:
        new_num = (initial[0] + initial[1])//2
        if new_num%2 == 0:
            initial[1] = new_num
        else:
            initial[0] = new_num
        list.append(initial)
        a += 1
    return list
```

Why does the above code return:

```
[[43, 44], [43, 44], [43, 44], [43, 44], [43, 44], [43, 44], [43, 44], [43, 44],  [43, 44], [43, 44]]
```

Rather than:

```
[[0, 50], [25, 50], [37, 50], [43, 50], [43, 46], [43,44], [43, 44], [43, 44], [43, 44], [43, 44]]
```

ie. The successive divisions rather than the final division 10 times over.

Thanks

Comment: You should get acquainted with the standard debugger in whichever IDE you are using. Helps a lot!

Answer (score 4):

First things first, **NEVER** name your variables with the builtin types names. In your case `list`. And your program doesnt work as expected, because

```
list.append(initial)
```

you are appending the reference to the same list again and again. At the end, all the elements in the list are pointing to the same list `initial`. To fix that, you can create a copy of `initial` like this and append it

```
list.append(initial[:])
```

Check this diagram out https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/edit/43c8-0c30-5288c928-a4fe-105f0a00c875. This might help you understand better.

Comment: But isn't the list "initial" is being changed each traversal of the loop?

Comment: @user2850514 Correct. But all the elements are pointing to `initial` only. So, at the end of the loop, what `initial` has will be the values of all the elements in the list.

Comment: @user2850514 Check this out https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/edit/43c8-0c30-5288c928-a4fe-105f0a00c875